# Is sweet whey better than acidic whey for Brunost cheese?

Tags: cheese, whey

I have some left over whey. I want to convert it to Brunost cheese? Is sweet whey better than acidic whey for this purpose? Any ideas on the quantities I can extract.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet whey is certainly better, since the process of making brunost involves caramelizing the sugar in the whey.

However, I wouldn't write off sour (cultured) whey, for example yogurt whey. It still contains quite a bit of lactose, despite the taste. So you can certainly try and see if you like the result. It won't be traditional, but it might be tasty.

What I would certainly avoid is salty whey (if you separated it from cheese curds after salting the curds). It would make for very, very salty brunost.